state variables returns undefined
I need help with managing react states, I can't seem to wrap my head around it.
I have a component that receives the id of a database entry from another page via useLocation, I then use that id with an axios get request to pull the rest of the data into an array. However, when I am trying to use the data from the get request as a defaultValue for an MUI TextField it doesn't render the data naturally, the states returns as undefined after the page loads. I have to set the TextField's key to the get request data (a work around I found in the web) to render. Then when I try to submit the form, the value from the Textfield displays as undefined though the Texfield contains the data from the get request.
const location = useLocation();
const [info, setInfo] = useState([]);

useEffect(()=>{
  axios
    .get("//localhost:3001/Info/" + location.state.id)
    .then((response)=>{
      setInfo(response.data);
  })
});

const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({});

const formik = useFormik({
  initialValues: {
    name: info.name
  },
  validationSchema: validationSchema,
  onSubmit: (values) => {
    console.log(values) // displays {name: undefined, .....}
  }
});

return(
  <>
    <Container>
      <form onSubmit = {formik.handleSubmit}>
        <TextField
          id = "name"
          label = "Name"
          name = "name"
          onChange = {formik.handleChange}
          onBlur = {formik.handleBlur}
          key = {info.name} //Textfield blank without setting key
          defaultValue = {info.name}
        />
        <Button type = "Submit"> Submit </Button>
      </form>
    </Container>
  </>
);

I am  expecting  the TextFields default values to render correctly without declaring a key as a work around. Also, I expect the values of the textfields to contain the initialvalues from the formik declaration on submit.

What does response.data look like?

There are few problems in your code, Please do the following fixes:

useEffect is called without dependencies

Update your useEffect as follows so that it gets triggered only on initial mount:
useEffect(()=>{
  axios
    .get("//localhost:3001/Info/" + location.state.id)
    .then((response)=>{
      setInfo(response.data);
  })
}, []);


Check if the property name exists before rendering:
if(!info.name){
  return <div>Loading</div>
}

return(
  <>
    <Container>
      <form onSubmit = {formik.handeSubmit}>
        <TextField
          id = "name"
       label = "Name"
       name = "name"
       onChange = {formik.handleChange}
       onBlur = {formik.handleBlur}
       key = {info.name} //Textfield blank without setting key
       defaultValue = {info.name}
     />
     <Button type = "Submit"> Submit </Button>
   </form>
 </Container>
 </>
 );


Change the initialisation of info. Make it an object since you are expecting an object from api. As:
const [info, setInfo] = useState({});






The code you pasted is the same as the original code, Im assuming you meant me to add location.state.id as dependency for useEffect, but that didnt make the app work.


App crashes, Info is an object.


App is just stuck at loading due to this code.



@ITCleanocean Please look carefully. I have added an [] as dependency array

Oh, missed that. I added the dependency but results didnt change

What does response.data look like? Add a console.log(response.data) before the line setInfo(response.data); and attach a screenshot of it in question.

So basically info is not an array but an object from api.  I have updated the answer based on that.

console.log(response.data) // {id: 2, name: 'Some name', middlename: 'Some middlename', lastname: 'some lastname', …}

Textfield now renders properly even without setting the key. But on submit, still returns undefined.

@ITCleanocean Can you check this codesandbox example I have created? Its working as expected for me. I have added console.log when user submits & Im gettings name data with value in object.

I created a Codesandbox with a working solution for the code that you provided; first, I had to switch the API method to call something that is not running on localhost, and second, I swapped out the custom component for a standard input.

You need to set enableReinitialize to true in your useFormik hook, otherwise the form won't reinitialize on the subsequent render that happens once the API promise method has been resolved.
The only prop you need, according to the docs with a very similar example, is value, which I've provided here. This sets the initial value of the field properly, and in conjunction with the onChange() and onBlur() methods, updates the form state correctly when the user interacts with the field.


there are one problem in your code
useEffect(()=>{
  axios
    .get("//localhost:3001/Info/" + location.state.id)
    .then((response)=>{
      setInfo([...response.data]);
  })
}, []);


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
